# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Value' not found - NOT a spelling error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a histogram, and I am trying to add a horizontal errorbar to it.

Here is the head of the graph.qc

```
 spec     Value Gain
1 CA  0.3649156  H.P
2 CA  0.3585836  H.P
3 CA  0.2731337  H.P
4 CA  0.3556054  H.P
5 CA  0.3294501  H.P
6 CA  0.3465670  H.P
```

here is the head of graph.compare

```
 Gain  spec       mean   median     n     sd    SE_H    ymin    ymax
  <chr> <fct>     <dbl>    <dbl> <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 H.NP  CA  -0.0333   -0.0310     70 0.0174 0.00208 -0.0507 -0.0159
2 H.NP  CAF    0.0324    0.0193     54 0.0530 0.00721 -0.0206  0.0853
3 H.NP  CAH    0.0490    0.0503     20 0.0698 0.0156  -0.0208  0.119 
4 H.NP  CAL    0.000585 -0.00805    28 0.0468 0.00884 -0.0462  0.0473
5 H.NP  CAM    0.00288  -0.0125     72 0.0480 0.00566 -0.0451  0.0509
6 H.NP  CAR    0.0211    0.00845    90 0.0383 0.00404 -0.0172  0.0595
```

Here is my code for a graph

NOTE: error only shows up if I don't include geom_errorbarh

```
  geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = 0.60, bins = 50)+
  geom_density(alpha=0.3)+
  geom_vline(data= graph.compare,  aes(xintercept = mean), color = "red", linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_vline(data=graph.compare, aes(xintercept = median), color="blue", linetype="dashed")+
  geom_errorbarh(data = graph.compare, aes(xmin = ymin, xmax = ymax), width =0.2)+
  facet_wrap(spec~., scales="free", ncol=3)+
  newtheme+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

When I run that , I get the error

`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Value' not found`

Not sure what's going on, I looked up some information and found I may need to spread and regather my data, but I dont' really understand why. Again, this is not an issue if I just comment out the geom_errorbarh, everything else (including geom_vline) will produce the graph without an issue.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you show the full code for the plot

Answer (score 0):

Althought the code is not complete, using the pieces of data you shared it was possible to reproduce the error. The error is produced because of the lack of variable `Value` in `graph.compare` (the function is looking for the initial coordinate defined in the plot) and also you need to set a `y` coordinate for the error bar. Here I have added in artesanal way a posible value for `Value` in the mentioned dataset but with your real data you should be able to add it properly. Also slight changes were made on `geom_errorbarh()` adding `y`. Next the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Add variable Value
graph.compare$Value <- c(0.15,0.025,0.048,-0.004,-0.005,0.015)
#Code
ggplot(graph.qc,aes(x=Value))+
  geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = 0.60, bins = 50)+
  geom_density(alpha=0.3)+
  geom_vline(data= graph.compare,  aes(xintercept = mean), color = "red", linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_vline(data=graph.compare, aes(xintercept = median), color="blue", linetype="dashed")+
  geom_errorbarh(data = graph.compare, aes(xmin = ymin, xmax = ymax,y=5), width =0.2)+
  facet_wrap(spec~., scales="free", ncol=3)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

Output:

[image]

Also for the sake of the example, I used `graph.qc` for the sketch of the plot.

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
graph.qc <- structure(list(spec = c("CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA"), 
    Value = c(0.3649156, 0.3585836, 0.2731337, 0.3556054, 0.3294501, 
    0.346567), Gain = c("H.P", "H.P", "H.P", "H.P", "H.P", "H.P"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))

#Data 2
graph.compare <- structure(list(Gain = c("H.NP", "H.NP", "H.NP", "H.NP", "H.NP", 
"H.NP"), spec = c("CA", "CAF", "CAH", "CAL", "CAM", "CAR"), mean = c(-0.0333, 
0.0324, 0.049, 0.000585, 0.00288, 0.0211), median = c(-0.031, 
0.0193, 0.0503, -0.00805, -0.0125, 0.00845), n = c(70L, 54L, 
20L, 28L, 72L, 90L), sd = c(0.0174, 0.053, 0.0698, 0.0468, 0.048, 
0.0383), SE_H = c(0.00208, 0.00721, 0.0156, 0.00884, 0.00566, 
0.00404), ymin = c(-0.0507, -0.0206, -0.0208, -0.0462, -0.0451, 
-0.0172), ymax = c(-0.0159, 0.0853, 0.119, 0.0473, 0.0509, 0.0595
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```